# Program execution process details

Tags: operating-system

Let's assume we have a simple `helloworld` program.
We run it like this:

```
> ./helloworld
> Hello, World!
```

But what exactly is happening here? How the program is actually executed?

I know that first, loader loads it to memory. But how? Can I do it manually like this:

```
> loader -flags helloworld
```

And what happens next?

How does it know from which point execution should start?

Where the initial "instruction pointer" is set and how does it advance?

How is it "unload" from memory after execution finishes?

Comment: The loader is supplied by the language runtime library (RTL), and is linked into the executable. It is not a stand-alone program, so you cannot invoke it from the command line. In the C language, the initial execution point is in the `main()` function, which is why it's required in each program. The initial instruction pointer (after the RTL has finished its job at loading) is the first line of `main()`. It is advanced as each instruction is executed. The unload at the end of `main()` is again handled by the RTL.

Comment: The loader is an OS internal and uses the executable header metadata to load. I do not know of a system where the loader can be invoked alone -  what would be the point?